# How to redirect on enter press within a component using Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I am writing a simple search component that searches an elasticsearch instance. I have all of the redux set up so my search query is stored in redux and the results are rendered when the user is on the /search page. My search bar is accessible from the navbar (on any page) and I was trying to redirect to the results page ("/search") when a user presses enter. I am using a top level  component in App.js.

I tried using  and history.push("/search"), but that changed the URL and the web page didn't render the new page.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import elasticsearchUtility from "../utilities/elastic-search-utility";

const styles = theme => ({
    container: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    margin: {
        margin: theme.spacing.unit,
    },
    cssLabel: {
        color: 'white',
        '&$cssFocused': {
            color: 'white',
        },
    },
    cssFocused: {
    },
    cssUnderline: {
        color: 'white',
    },
    cssOutlinedInput: {
        '&$cssFocused $notchedOutline': {
            borderColor: 'white',
        },
    },
    notchedOutline: {
        borderWidth: '1px',
        borderColor: 'white !important'
    },
});

class Search extends Component{
    state = {
        searchQuery: ""
    };

    onChange = event => {
        this.props.updateQuery(event.target.value);
    };

    render() {
        const {searchQuery, classes} = this.props;

        return (
            <div className={this.props.classes.container}>
                <TextField
                    fullWidth={true}
                    className={classes.margin}
                    InputLabelProps={{
                        classes: {
                            root: classes.cssLabel,
                            focused: classes.cssFocused,
                        },
                    }}
                    InputProps={{
                        classes: {
                            root: classes.cssOutlinedInput,
                            focused: classes.cssFocused,
                            notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline,
                        },
                    }}
                    onChange={this.onChange}
                    label="Service search"
                    variant="outlined"
                    id="custom-css-outlined-input"
                    value={searchQuery}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        query: state.searchQuery
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        updateQuery: (query) => {
            dispatch(search(query))
        }
    }
};

function search(value) {
    return {type: "SEARCH", value};
}

Search.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(
    connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        mapDispatchToProps
    )(Search)
);
```

I am expecting the page to render my search results when the user presses enter (initiates a search), in actuality the /search is being pushed to the URL but the page isn't being rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

onChange = event => {
    this.props.updateQuery(event.target.value);
    this.props.history.replace('/search');

};

export default withStyles(styles)(
    connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        mapDispatchToProps
    )(withRouter)(Search)
);
```

You need to wrap your component with withRouter and use like this.

Comment: I am getting the error TypeError: Cannot set property 'props' of undefined. I think the props.history is undefined? NVM solved, see edit.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Need to wrap the `connect` in default export with `withRouter` and use this.props.history.push("/search").

```
export default withStyles(styles)(withRouter(
    connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        mapDispatchToProps
    )(Search))
);
```